# Como determino si una string empieza con cierta palabra y entonces de ser asi elimino esa palabra y guardo eso en otra variable con regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, condiciones

Como la API del traductor tiene usos limitados solo pondre que detecte idioma en caso de que el usuario ingrese su texto empezando con 'Tr:' o con 'Tr: ' en ese caso debo quitar eso y mandar a traducir la cadena sin eso, pero de no ser el caso que no mande a traducir y que pase el texto directo.

```py
import re

input_text = 'Tr: Hi how are you?'

trad_bool = False

#Si COMIENZA con 'Tr:' o con 'Tr: ' extrae todo lo siguiete y lo guarda en la variable input_text

if():

    #quito el 'Tr:' o con 'Tr: ', y lo guardo en input_text_2
    input_text_2 = "" # <-- deberia quedar 'Hi how are you?'
    trad_bool = True


else:
    input_text_2 = input_text #Queda igual
    trad_bool = True

if(trad_bool == True):
    #Lo debo traducir(uso API del traductor)

elif(trad_bool == False):
    #No lo necesito traducir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma fácil y sencilla de hacerlo es como dices tu, con expresiones regulares.

```py
import re
#armamos nuestra expresion regular
regex = re.compile(r'Tr:\s{,}')
```

En la expresión regular le decimos que debe de tener los caracteres `Tr:` seguido de varios o ningún espacio.

```py
input_text = 'Tr:Hi how are you?'
trad_bool = False

if regex.match(input_text): #verificamos si hay concidencia
    print("coincidencia")
    separacion = regex.split(input_text) #separamos el texto
    texto = " ".join(separacion[1:]) #obtenemos lo que sigue despues de Tr: 
    print(texto)
else:
    print("no coincide")
```

**resultado**

```
coincidencia
Hi how are you?
```

La ventaja de la expresión `re.compile(r'Tr:\s{,}')` es que si el usuario ingresa varios espacios igual cumplirá la condición e igual hara la separación y obtendrás la misma cadena

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Hay bastante que mejorar en el código. He aquí la versión propuesta:

```
input_text = 'Tr: Hi how are you?'

#Si COMIENZA con 'Tr:' o con 'Tr: ' extrae todo lo siguiete y lo guarda en la variable input_text

trad_bool = input_text.startswith('Tr:')

if trad_bool:
    input_text_2 = input_text[3:].lstrip()
    print("llamar al traductor")
else:
    input_text_2 = input_text #Queda igual
    print("no necesita traducir")
```

No necesitas expresiones regulares para esto. Puedes usar el método `cadena.startswith(subcadena)` que comprueba que la `cadena` comience con `subcadena`.

En nuestro caso, basta con chequear que la cadena comienza con `Tr:` y simplemente borrar cualquier blanco que venga a continuación.

Usando este método podemos inicializar de inmediato `trad_bool`, dejando establecido si necesitamos o no traducir.

Si toca traducir, extraemos el texto mismo a partir de la cuarta posición, usando `lstrip` para eliminar cualquier espacio adicional antes del texto mismo.

Comment: lo que me queda en duda es que si ponen 'Tr:' osea ponen el texto sin el espacio entonces quedaria trad_bool = Falsey no se haria la traduccion

Comment: La comparación con contra "Tr:", sin espacios. Si aceptas "Tr:" como válido, aceptas también "Tr:" seguido de cualquier cosa, incluyendo espacio.

Comment: el tema es que al poner print(input_text_2) imprimira solo el primer caracter siguiente sea o no espacio

Comment: @ElectrisikVocal. Cierto, era `[3:]` en lugar de `[3]`. Edite ya la respuesta.

Comment: Listo, no se me habia ocurrido la alternativa de hacerlo sin regex. Muchas gracias por la ayuda